# Office-js - Saving Word document as read only

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I've created a Task Pane add-in for Word which has following function:
    Once you've finished working on your document it's sent to our service as a pdf and assigned an ID. The ID, token and more is saved in the word document as settings. In our service it has a certain status (new, in progress, complete etc).

So when you re-open your Word document it automatically pulls the status if the token is still active.

Anyway, I've got that all working fine but what I'd like to do is to save the Word Document as read only when it's sent to the service. If the user decides to change the word document the Add-in clears all settings and it would have to be re-sent to the service.

I can only find functionality to save the document without any parameters or to check what mode the document is currently in without being able to alter it.

TLDR:

Is there a way to save the the Word document as read only with the Office-js API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting scenario, but unfortunately Not possible today. please add request to our user voice channel https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

maybe as an alternative you can try to add more logic/permissions to set the settings.

thanks